# php, conversion of string date to DateTime in request

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

So I currently have a request sending to a function:

```
$request->date
```

and date, in this case, is a string "2019-10-15"

The function is expecting `\DateTime $scheduled` as the argument this date is going to

How can I properly (using Carbon/laravel) convert this date string to dateTime in this request portion where it's being sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller where you need the date, use this:

```
$date = Carbon::parse($request->date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply instantiate a `DateTime` from that date

```php
$scheduled = new \DateTime($request->date);
```

Comment: OP wants to do with Carbon though.

Comment: @vivek_23 not really, the OP wants to do it in laravel, using built-in PHP functions is completely valid here. Carbon can be used but it's not mandatory at all

Comment: @Kaddath I do know that but OP said `How can I properly (using Carbon/laravel) convert this...`

Comment: @vivek_23 there is already a good answer using `Carbon`, i'm just providing a simpler alternative. This answer might give another point of view to the developer about using Framework specific ways or PHP native ways so for me it's a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Laravel have no casts support inside request object, I would use `passedValidation` inside the custom request object:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'date' => 'required|date',
    ];
}

protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
        'date' => Carbon::parse($this->get('date'))
    ]);
}

public function getDate(): \DateTime
{
    return $this->get('date');
}
```

Getter is optional, I like it just because it defines a type.

In Laravel we have a Request layer where all this stuff should be handled, controllers might get cluttered if we put casting and parsing into them.

This has not been appropriately tested.